# How to include one c# file into another c# file?

Tags: c#

How to include one c# file into another c# file?

I have two c# file like one is test.cs and another one is main.cs. I want to include test.cs into main.cs.

test.cs file code

```
// you can use Console.WriteLine for debugging 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Solution
{
   public bool solution(long number1, int[,] arr1,int dim_2,int dim_3) 
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

main.cs code

```
using System;
include test.cs;
class Group
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        long  number1 =  5;
        int [,] arr1 = new int[,] {{0, 0},{1, 1},{2, 2},{3, 3},{4, 4}};
        int dim_2 = 5;
        int dim_3 = 2;
        Solution object_class =  new Solution();
        bool result = object_class.solution ( number1, arr1, dim_2, dim_3 );
        Console.WriteLine("Return :");
        Console.WriteLine( result );
    }
}
```

what i am doing wrong here?? Please Help me.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You should just `using` the other class, not `#include` it. Why do you want to include?

Comment: you must have to add both files in same project..... and include test.cs. is not required here.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is because both files are not added in the same project.

**If you are using Visual Studio.**

To add `test.cs` in the Group class project.

> Go to Solution Explorer -> Add Existing item -> Browse your file i.e.
>   **test.cs** -> OK

**If you are using DOS mode.**

Make sure that both files must be in same folder.

---

**And in either case. first delete `include test.cs;` from Main file. then Compile & RUN**

Answer (score 1):

I created a new .cs file, called it Class1.cs , I am working in vs code.
Content of file, with one method:

```
namespace greeting

public class Class1
{
    public static void Hello()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello there!");
               
    }
}
```

And simply called from file with Main method, with
namespace in front:

```
greeting.Class1.Hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

We create object of classes declared in other source code files with the way you have already followed:

```
Solution object_class =  new Solution();
```

Provided that the Solution class is declared in a source code file in the same project (console application as I can infer from your post), you don't have to mark the `Solution` class as a public. Otherwise, you should mark it as a public. Actually, you have to do so in case of this class is going to be used outside of your current project.

Your problem, I think is about namespaces. You might have declared this class inside a folder. Anyways, the way to solve this is to right click on the name of the `Solution` and then click resolve references.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET C# Classes

this solution was helpfull for class files outside the App_Code
you need add follow line in every page(aspx) or usercontrol(asc)

```
<%@ Assembly Src="~/App_Ctrl/PraxisPdfs/class_pdf.cs" %>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? This seems like an answer to a different question. Once the C# code is compiled, ASP.NET should be unaware to whether there were includes in the original C# code. Or, is your point, that it _only_ works for code that _is_ precompiled, but for dynamically compiled code in `App_Code`, you need additional steps? If so, did you mean for your `Assembly` directive to point to `/App_Code`? Some clarification would go a long way here.

Comment: My english is not so good. I wanted to show how to assign a c# class to a c# file(aspx or ascx) that is not in App_Code. The compilation of the website is static. Sorry if I didn't understand the question correctly.